# How to make text in one element appear inline with text in another element?

Tags: html, css

I'm having an issue with css trying to get the text of one div to be floated left on another div with the text displayed as in the screen shot. I cannot simply move the text because of a complex wordpress theme issue.

I've tried making the top div display:inline; and flex. Then floating the bottom div left and combinations of this for several hours, this leads to my question below.

Is it even possible to display a div like this?

Note that the "content here" text needs to be floated left on the "more text".

Here is a screenshot of how I want the layout:

[image]

Comment: If you add some code example - it would help a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Settings both `div`s to `display: inline;` should be all it takes. You don't need floats or flex-layouts. (See the snippet below).

I highly recommend studying the CSS Box Model in greater depth:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 150px;
}

.more-text,
.content-text {
  display: inline;
}

.more-text {
  background: green;
}

.content-text {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="more-text">
    Random text here More text
  </div>
  <div class="content-text">
    content text Random text here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I was able to read up on what you showed and simply made everything display inline :)

Comment: Glad I could help!